# Can a word have two separate etymologies?

Tags: etymology

A separate etymology for the spelling and another for the meaning of the word?

Comment: Does *island* count?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, per the *OED*, the word *doubt* comes to us from the Old French *douter*, no *b*, and in the 14th century, the English word had no *b* either.  But those familiar with Latin on both sides of the Channel, inserted the *b* to indicate that the word ultimately came from the Latin *dubitare*.  The pronunciations remained unchanged, so the *b* was silent. By the 17th century, the silent *b* was a fixture in modern English but had been abandoned in modern French.  So the English etymology for meaning is French; the etymology for spelling, Latin.  You may not wish to accept this as an example because the *French* etymology is Latin.

Of course, sometimes those familiar with Latin were more familiar with Latin than with the derivation of English from Latin.  The word *scissors* originally didn't have an initial *s*, coming to us from the Old French *cisoria*, a cutting implement.  The French word came from the Latin *caedere* (to cut), past participle *caesum*.  The initial *s* was added during the 16th century in the mistaken impression that the word came from the Latin *scindere* (to cut), past participle *scissum*.  So the correct etymology for meaning involves *caedere*; the mistaken etymology for spelling, *scindere*.